# datepicker in webpage on Android phone

Tags: android, datepicker

I'm writing a web page to use on Android phones only. This is an html page and i have some javascript elements in there.

All i want is a pre-populated field with the date and then allow the user to select the date to choose a different date if they wish.

Could someone please recommend the required tools for this? i.e html, javascript, query etc.

Some methods i've researched don't seem to work.

Thanks Steve

Comment: I had some responses here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588857/need-a-consistent-timepicker-gizmo-for-mobile-web-site